# UIWebView not loading HTML String when failed to load URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, html, uiwebview

I am trying to load an "Error page" inside `webView didFailLoadWithError` delegate method when UIWebView failed to load page from URL. I tried to load the error page directly and its working perfectly. Here my code given below,

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
//    [webView stopLoading];

errorMessage    = (errorMessage==nil?@"Sorry, there was an error loading the chapter":errorMessage);
refreshMessage  = (refreshMessage==nil?@"Try reloading this chapter":refreshMessage);

NSURL *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"error_icon_2x" withExtension:@"png" subdirectory:@"/www/img/"];
NSURL *cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myexp" withExtension:@"css" subdirectory:@"/www/css/"];


NSString *errorHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"%@\"><script type='text/javascript'>function callReloadPDF() { window.location  = 'ios:reloadPDF'; }</script></head><div style=\"position: relative; top: 35%%; transform: translateY(-50%%); \" class=\"errorPDFViewer\"><div style=\"\"><img src=\"%@\" width=\"30px\" height=\"30px\" class=\"newexpimgerroricon\"/></div><br /><div class=\"newexpsorrymessagelabel\">'%@'</div><div style=\"margin: 1% 30%;text-align: center; \"><button class=\"btnreloadPage\" id=\"btnreloadPage' + index + '\" onclick='callReloadPDF()'>'%@'</button></div></div>", cssPath, imagePath, errorMessage, refreshMessage];

NSLog(@"errorHTML: %@", errorHTML);

[webView loadHTMLString:errorHTML baseURL:nil];

}
```

Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks!!!

Comment: I tried your code in Delegate method and it loads html data perfectly without CSS and image.

Comment: @Dheeraj Did you try to initiate a network based load request and forced to fail loading? I found something interesting in apple document "If, after initiating a network-based load request, you must release your web view for any reason, you must cancel the pending request before releasing the web view."

Comment: I tried a network based load request and same content loaded when delegate method was called.Also read the apple document.

Comment: Then I dont understand my problem. For me its not loading :(

Comment: is the delegate method getting called?

Comment: Yes.. Everything working perfect except this :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66719/discussion-between-dheeraj-singh-and-augustine-p-a).